# "Residence time" of a photon?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

E.g. CO2 absorbs and emits electromagnetic radiation at some frequencies.

If the CO2 molecule is in a continuous electromagentic field, it will absorb and emit. What is the time between absorption and emission of a photon ?
How can this time be calculated?

In a classical calculation the emitted field from a dipole will lag 1/4 wavelength.

Comment: atoms and molecules belong to the realm of quantum mechanics, and photons are quantum mechanical particles . One cannot define such a time as it is not the same photon that is emitted, if absorbed.

Comment: According to encyclopedia Britannica, average time of just exited electron going to ground state through spontaneous emission is about $1-10ns$.

Comment: It depends on the temperature of the CO2 .... in blackbody radiation the net power emitted can be calculated.  If equilibrium is assumed with another body then emission equals absorption.

Answer (score 0):

Photons are indistinguishable so in general you can't identify a particular timescale on which a particular photon was absorbed and then emitted because there is no fact of the matter about whether the absorbed and emitted photons are the same photon.

In some circumstances, e.g. - in quantum tunnelling, you can say that in a particular region the amount of energy increased for a particular period and then decreased back to its original level and this is called the dwell time:

https://winful.engin.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/376/2018/01/physics_reports_review_article__2006_.pdf

This would depend on the context in which the atom emitted and absorbed light there might be a sensible way of talking about the dwell time. For a review of some experiments on atoms and molecules specifically see Peng, Liang-You, et al. "Tracing and controlling electronic dynamics in atoms and molecules by attosecond pulses." Physics Reports 575 (2015): 1-71.

https://faculty.pku.edu.cn/_tsf/00/0B/73QNZfNZFV3a.pdf

For some more explanation of indistinguishability see

https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.14214

Comment: Thanks. I can understand the difficulty to define "dwell time" or "residence time".
I have read papers where they claim that there is microseconds between absorption and emission (CO2 in homogeneous EM-field). I have some problem to understand how they can state this time. Any comments to this is helpful.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a paper?

Comment: Not sure if this is the "best" paper, but anyhow...

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/greenhouse-model-co2-cyril-huijsmans

"The Einstein A coefficient for spontaneous emission is around 1 per second (Hitran data base). "

My understanding is that people interpret this as if it is a long time between absorption and emission. Some (friends) claim that when CO2 absorbs a photon, it will collide with other gas moelcules before it can emitt the photon, meaning the the CO2 molecule looses the absorbed energy by collision (wich the call "thermalisation").

Comment: You can look at the timescales under which a molecule interacts by thermalisation and absorption by comparing the evolution operators for each interaction.

Comment: Thanks again. I am still a bit confused about the timescales. Absorption/emission (in a continuous field) compared to collisions with other molecules.

My interpretation is that the timescale absorption/emission is very short. Magnitude 1/frequency. In a classicala model (dipole in em-field) the time lag between emitted field/ incident field is very short. To me it seems strange if QM gives a completely different answer. A molecule is rather "big" and the vibrational spectrum is almost "continuous". In my eyes that classical approximation should be rather OK.

Comment: My expectation would be that for carbon dioxide molecules in the atmosphere the interactions between them won't be coherent and the light interacting with it won't be coherent either in any way that would cause trouble, so treating such a molecule as a classical oscillator at the frequencies explained by a quantum mechanical treatment of an individual molecule should work.